# New PreferenceScreen doesn't open after enabling

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, androidx

I've been using AndroidX Preference library for my project. This project has  main menu and  sub menu. I have set the dependency between CheckBoxPreference in main menu and PreferenceScreen in submenu. When CheckBox is checked, PreferenceScreen becomes enabled, but I can't open the submenu.

If I delete the dependency, everything works fine!

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox1"
        android:summaryOff="Description of checkbox 1 off"
        android:summaryOn="Description of checkbox 1 on"
        android:title="CheckBox 1">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    <ListPreference
        android:dependency="checkbox1"
        android:entries="@array/entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/entry_values"
        android:key="list"
        android:summary="Description of list"
        android:title="List">
    </ListPreference>
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox2"
        android:summary="Description of checkbox 2"
        android:title="CheckBox 2">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="screen"
        android:dependency="checkbox2"
        android:summary="Description of screen"
        android:title="Screen">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="checkbox3"
            android:summary="Description of checkbox 3"
            android:title="CheckBox 3">
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <PreferenceCategory
            android:key="category1"
            android:summary="Description of category 1"
            android:title="Category 1">
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="checkbox4"
                android:summary="Description of checkbox 4"
                android:title="CheckBox 4">
            </CheckBoxPreference>
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory
            android:key="category2"
            android:dependency="checkbox3"
            android:summary="Description of category 2"
            android:title="Category 2">
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="chb5"
                android:summary="Description of checkbox 5"
                android:title="CheckBox 5">
            </CheckBoxPreference>
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="chb6"
                android:summary="Description of checkbox 6"
                android:title="CheckBox 6">
            </CheckBoxPreference>
        </PreferenceCategory>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

PreferencesFragment.java

```java
public class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference;
    PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory;


    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "my_preference_fragment";

    public PreferencesFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

        checkBoxPreference = findPreference("checkbox3");
        preferenceCategory = findPreference("category2");
        preferenceCategory.setEnabled(checkBoxPreference.isChecked());

        checkBoxPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                preferenceCategory.setEnabled(checkBoxPreference.isChecked());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PreferencesActivity.java

```java
public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartScreenCallback{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(PreferencesFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new PreferencesFragment();
            }
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferencesFragment())
                .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceStartScreen(PreferenceFragmentCompat caller,
                                           PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        PreferencesFragment preferencesFragment = new PreferencesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(PreferenceFragmentCompat.ARG_PREFERENCE_ROOT, preferenceScreen.getKey());
        preferencesFragment.setArguments(args);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, preferencesFragment,
                preferenceScreen.getKey());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(preferenceScreen.getKey());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;
    }

}
```

I expect the starting a new Preference, but actually I've got this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.allexfiloenko.lesson62_preferences_enable, PID: 9233
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dependency "checkbox2" not found for preference "screen" (title: "Screen"
        at androidx.preference.Preference.registerDependency(Preference.java:1393)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.onAttached(Preference.java:1357)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceGroup.onAttached(PreferenceGroup.java:444)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.bindPreferences(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:484)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onViewCreated(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:272)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2076)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1821)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a supported use case, and nesting a PreferenceScreen in general is no longer recommended.

Instead I would recommend a separate fragment, with a separate hierarchy. You can use a Preference in your first screen, to link to the second screen. Then this Preference would have the dependency, and this should work fine.

For interest's sake, I think the actual issue here is that after you move to the new screen, the outer hierarchy no longer exists, but the PreferenceScreen that is the new root still has this dependency, so it looks for the preference "checkbox2" which no longer exists :)

See the [Settings guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#split_your_hierarchy_into_multiple_screens) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer)  Yes, I've read the Settings guide and everything become clear about nested Preferences. But I don't understand one thing - do I need to create new activity for each Fragment or no?

Comment: Nope, you don't need to, you can just replace the existing fragment. See the [example project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-preferences/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidx/preference/sample/MainActivity.kt) for a complete example :)